# Nginx conditional proxy pass configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have 2 different ( Node & Angular ) applications running under a domain. I am trying to configure nginx in way to serve like, whenever anyone access "domain.com" it should serve the node app running on port 4200 and if someone access "domain.com/admin" it should serve the contents from Angular app. Below is my nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;

    server_name domain.com

}


server {
    listen   443 default_server ssl;
    ssl on;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/domain/public_html/angular/dist;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

 
    location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_redirect off;
    }
     location /admin {
         try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    }
```

The problem I am facing now is all the requests including /admin is getting proxy passed. Is there any way I can restrict the /admin requests to not get proxy passed? Below is the nginx log.

---

### connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/admin", host: "domain.com"

Can someone please shed some light to get this resolved?

Comment: You should change `try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;` - otherwise it will go back to the first location block.

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, that didn't worked though. It was throwing redirection errors.
------------
 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/admin/index.html", client: x.x.x.x, server:domain.com, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
------------

Comment: You need to create the `/admin/index.html` file. I thought it was obvious ...

Comment: Files are there under "/home/domain/public_html/angular/dist" folder.

Comment: If `/admin/index.html` file exists - then the only way to find out the cause for infinite redirection is to enable the debug log in nginX.